# CMake: how to install lots of static files, but only when necessary?

Tags: cmake

Preface: I'm new to cmake and only have a barely-passing knowledge of how it works, so this may not be as hard as it looks to me. :-)

For various "legacy" reasons, I'm using cmake 2.8.12, and I have a large complicated project that I did not create, but now I'm trying to figure out how to make it build faster. In the top-level CMakeLists.txt file that drives everything, there are lots of targets defined for the app build and other things, and at the end it has something like "include(StaticResources)".

StaticResources.cmake defines (and at the end, calls) a function that just iterates over a ton of dirs with static files and installs each of those dirs to the output dir, as well as installing a few explicitly enumerate files, some of which are renamed.

The problem I'm trying to eliminate is that even if a build does nothing at all, this function takes many seconds as cmake goes through and visits each dir/file to see if it needs to be copied.  I'm trying to figure out how to structure this so that it doesn't even look at that stuff if nothing has changed.

Any ideas?  Things I have thought of trying (but am not sure how):
- possibly make that StaticResources function depend on the main app target in some way such that it only runs when the main app has to be built (this isn't ideal, of course, because lots things can change that app without requiring resources to be deployed)
- having a StaticResources "build" target that computes a hash of the state of all of these static resources files and writes it to an output file only if something is changed, then having this static resources function install that target with custom code that actually installs the static files.  It seems like this would make sure that the install is only considered if/when the resources actually change, but I'm not sure if cmake will allow me to "install(StaticResources "

Comment: Several seconds for CMake is ok. You don't have to run it for every build. If it is executed for installation, several seconds isn't bad neither. So, what is the question?

Comment: I'm afraid that this legacy codebase is simply abusing "install"  and shouldn't be installing every time one builds. :-)  That's the state it is in currently, so I was trying to figure out how to make install smarter, but I think you're hinting at the right thing, which is to make it not necessary to install.